# How to programatically determine if 2013 running in '14 compatibility mode' (SP 2010)

Tags: 2013, object-model

How can you programmatically determine if a site collection is running in ['14 compatibility mode' (so it looks like SharePoint 2010)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/07/22/running-sharepoint-2013-in-2010-mode-and-solution-compatibilitylevel.aspx)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check [`SPWeb.UIVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.uiversion.aspx) to see what UI version the site is currently using:

```
switch(web.UIVersion)
{
    case 3:
        // 2007
        break;

    case 4:
        // 2010 & 2013 "14 mode"
        break;

    case 15:
        // 2013
        break;
}
```